# Selecionar child após usar querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, html

Estou querendo alterar alguns atributos dentro dos campos: **ul > li**. No caso trocarei a a.url e img.src, porem estou usando um for para alterar os campos é usando no modo **artistSimimarChild[i]** como posso acessar o ul > li > a e ul > li > a > img ?

HTML:

```
<ul class="ui-artist-related">
    <li class="ui-artist-related__column ui-artist-related__artist"><a href="#"><img src="assets/images/profiles/katyperry.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li class="ui-artist-related__column ui-artist-related__artist"><a href="#"><img src="assets/images/profiles/kesha.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li class="ui-artist-related__column ui-artist-related__artist"><a href="#"><img src="assets/images/profiles/arianagrande.jpg" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
const artistSimilar = document.querySelector(".ui-artist-related"),
artistSimimarChild = document.querySelectorAll("li.ui-artist-related__artist");
```

O modo que pensei mais próximo seria fazer:

```
var 1 = document.querySelectorAll("li.ui-artist-related__artist > a")[i];
var 2 = document.querySelectorAll("li.ui-artist-related__artist > a > img")[i];
```

Porem não quero ficar criando varias var para selecionar um campo especifico e no final ficar uma bagunça o meu código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para o html indicado pode utilizar o seletor que tinha indicado `li.ui-artist-related__artist > a` para chegar aos links. Depois de cada link chega à imagem que está dentro dele utilizando a propriedade `childNodes` e acedendo ao primeiro que é a posição `0`:

```js
const as = document.querySelectorAll("li.ui-artist-related__artist > a");

for (let a of as){
  let imagem = a.childNodes[0];
  console.log(a.getAttribute("href")," tem imagem ", imagem.getAttribute("src"));
}
```

```html
<ul class="ui-artist-related">
  <li class="ui-artist-related__column ui-artist-related__artist">
    <a href="link1"><img src="assets/images/profiles/katyperry.jpg" /></a>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-artist-related__column ui-artist-related__artist">
    <a href="link2"><img src="assets/images/profiles/kesha.jpg" /></a>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-artist-related__column ui-artist-related__artist">
    <a href="link3"><img src="assets/images/profiles/arianagrande.jpg" /></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Para alterar os atributos pode utilizar a função `setAttribute`:

```
for (let i=0;i < as.length; ++i){ 
  as[i].setAttribute("href", "novolink"+i);
  as[i].childNodes[0].setAttribute("src", "novosource"+i);
}
```

Documentação:

- [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes)
- [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)
- [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)